# htaccess rewrite not working on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to perform a url rewrite where a url like "http://localhost/mywork/product/MTg=/productinfo/" should appear like "http://localhost/mywork/MTg="

Also, the "MTg=" is dynamic and will be varying.

I am not sure as to how to achieve it, can anyone please suggest what RewriteRule i should be writting in my .htaccess

Comment: Is `/productinfo/` a static value? Why do you want `=` in pretty URL?

Comment: yes /productinfo/  is a static string

Answer (score 0):

Create `mywork/.htaccess` file it doesn't exist and have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mywork/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1/productinfo/ [L]
```

Comment: Hello Anubhava, thanks for replying. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Where is this htaccess located? What is exact URL you used for testing? Are there more rules in this?